# ssh proxy command with netcat

Tags: linux, encryption, ssh

In example like this:

```
Host destination
  ProxyCommand ssh gateway nc %h %p
```

Is the connection between the gateway and the destination encrypted? I am confused because I have 2 hypotheses and both are not convincing:

- It's not encrypted. The stdin in source goes through the source-gateway ssh connection encrypted, and get decrypted before being passed to `nc`, i.e nc's stdin is the same as stdin into ssh client at source. But I think the `%p` is 22, the ssh port -- which doesn't fit with this hypothesis.
- It's encrypted, the sshd daemon at gateway pass to nc encrypted data. Then say instead of executing `nc`, we are executing `cat`, does sshd daemon pass it the encrypted data too? That doesn't sound right either.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is encrypted! Just to understand well what is going on here:

```
[ client $ ssh destination ]
  |
  '-> [ gateway $ nc destination 22 ]
        |
        '-> [ destination $ whatever]
```

On client you run just `ssh destination`. This is translated into `ssh gateway nc destination 22`.

So first executed command is `ssh gateway` with command. We have encrypted first step for sure.

The `nc destination 22` command is run in this session on `gateway` server. And it does basically the thing that it redirects all I/O to the `destination` host, just as it is (but we are already in encrypted channel!).

So you will do once more key exchange with and authentication with `destination` and after it will succeed, you will get probably shell prompt there. So it is again encrypted.